# So + adjective + that / so + adjective + (as) + to-infinitive / too + adjective + to-infinitive

Tags: prepositions

I have two questions that have made me confused since yesterday.

a) Is it possible to use "***so+adjective+to-infinitive***" form instead of using "***so+adjective+as+to-infinitive***"? Is it possible to make the meaning remain the same?

b) I saw this explanation in the internet says "***This structure(too + adjective + to- infintive) is used to explain why someone can’t do something***". But in my example(the fourth sentence), the sentence isn't explain why she can't do something. The sentence explainig why she can do but the thing she do is too idiotic.

> 1-She is ***so stupid that*** she believed his so-called claims
>
> 2-She is ***so stupid as to*** believe his so-called claims
>
> 3-She is ***so stupid to*** believe his so-called claims
>
> 4-She is ***too stupid to*** believe his so-called claims.

Answer (score 3):

1- this is grammatical and the meaning is “She was stupid; therefore she believed his false claims.” EDIT: another (maybe more accurate?) “translation” might be: “She was really stupid, which made her do stupid things like believe his false claims.” or (2nd edit) “She was very stupid, illustrated (or shown) by the fact that she believed his false claims.”

2- this one seems grammatical as well. It means “She is stupid enough that she *would* believe his false claims.”

3- Also grammatical. It means “She *does* believe his false claims, therefore she is stupid.”

4- grammatical but semantically weird. “Too smart” would make more sense. As you have it here with “too stupid” it means “She doesn’t believe his false claims because she is stupid (not smart enough).”

Comment: Yes, but I'm not *quite* convinced that ***therefore*** correctly describes the relationship between the two assertions in the first example. I can't think of any short alternative expression, but to me it's more a matter of (assertion 1) ***she is  very stupid*** ... (linking element) ***the degree of her stupidity is illustrated by*** ... 
(assertion 2) ***she believed his false claims***.

Comment: @Lambie I think this sentence "She is too smart to believe his false claims." is quite sarcastic. I only use when I want to make fun of her.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden My point is this: The analysis is correct, and you have to change stupid to smart to make sentence 4) make sense. With stupid, it does not make sense. With 4), it is a very typical utterance and not sarcastic at all, necessarily.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree. I used “therefore” to simplify things, but probably something like “which is shown by the fact that” would be more accurate.

Comment: Excellent edit. It might look like a fine point of detail, but I can imagine that for some learners it's useful information.

Comment: Thank you everyone. What if I say "She was so sad to cry", it seems weird to me even though it is similiar to my third example("She is so stupid to believe his so-called claims"). I can't explain why it is weird.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden you are right thinking this is weird (“She was so sad to cry”). “She was so sad that she (eventually) cried” - this works and means “her sadness led her to cry”. “She was so X to cry”- I feel like X has to be a judgment, like “stupid” or “wrong” or “right” for this to make any sense. Or something that the speaker would think about her if she cried. “Sad” doesn’t work because it’s obvious and not the speaker’s judgment of her crying.

Comment: I know in another question’s comments you brought up the word “ready” as a counterexample- this does work here too. “She was so ready to cry”- I guess that is an exception to what I just said.

Comment: Hi :) . I have a hard time understanding the function and meaning of "to" in the third example. It is obviously not indicating purpose or reaction ?

Comment: @TalhaÖzden “She is so stupid to believe his so-called claims” - “to” is kind of like “because” here, I guess. “She is so stupid because she believes his so-called claims” has more or less the same meaning. Or “The fact that she believes his so-called claims means she is so stupid.” Does that help?

Comment: Yeah it helps :) But I can't find any dictionary or book to find this meaning or function of "to" to understand better. In dictionaries they say "to is used as part of an infinitive" but the specific meaning that "to" gives to the sentence varies with the verbs or adjectives that is used with "to".

Comment: @TalhaÖzden I see a definition that I think matches this usage in the Cambridge dictionary: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/to?q=To “used after some adjectives:
It's not likely to happen.
Three months is too long to wait.
She's not strong enough to go hiking up mountains.” Unfortunately this is not very descriptive - and you’re right, “(adj) to (verb)” can have slightly varied meanings of “to”. You can use “(adj) for (present progressive verb)” in a similar way e.g. “She’s stupid for believing him”.